# Order of items in QMap and QMultiMap

Tags: qt, qmap, qmultimap

I would like to use `QMultiMap` (which is derived from `QMap`) to store key/value pairs. Since I can have keys multiple times I would prefer to use `QMultiMap`.

Assume I would insert the following pairs in the given order:

```
"C" -> 5
"A" -> 10
"B" -> 77
"B" -> 1
"X" -> 314159
```

When iterating over the map (using java style iterators preferably) I need the order of equal-key-pairs to be preserved. I.e. `"B" -> 77` and `"B" -> 1` should appear exactly in insertion order when iterating. The order between keys that are different does not matter.

Unfortunately the documentation doesn't tell something about that detail. It says

> With QMap, the items are always sorted by key

but it does not say if/how it sorts equal keys.

Does `QMap` preserve the insertion order of pairs with equal keys or can it be preserved in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Qt documentation about `QMap::iterator` :

> Unlike QHash, which stores its items in an arbitrary order, QMap
>   stores its items ordered by key. Items that share the same key
>   (because they were inserted using QMap::insertMulti(), or due to a
>   unite()) will appear consecutively, from the most recently to the
>   least recently inserted value.

So it seems that `QMap` keeps the reversed insertion order of pairs with equal keys.

Comment: That is what I was searching for. Thanks. This means the solution for my problem should be to iterate over the map in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload `QMap::insertMulti(const_iterator pos, const Key &key, const T &value)`, where `pos` is a "hint" and you can pass `constBegin()` or `constEnd()`, or some iterator in the middle of the collection where you want to make the insertion. This is the way to dictate the order when you have duplicate keys.

I think it might be luck that one can generally see the order preserved as though it were a stack...